# Angular 6 Froala Editor [(froalaModel)]="editorContent" not working

Tags: angular, editor, wysiwyg, froala

I am using [Froala Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-froala-wysiwyg-base) in Angular 6 Application. When I was try to load HTML String in Froala Editor using [(froalaModel)]="editorContent" it doesn't work.

**HTML Template Code**

```
        <div class="form-control" name="body" formControlName="body"  [froalaEditor]="options" [(froalaModel)]="article.body"></div>
```

Actually data is binding perfectly to Editor but Pre Binded Content is not showing in the editor. If i start typing in the editor it change the value to the binded variable. Problem is only this, content of variable article.body is not visible in editor.

Comment: what's  the error?

Comment: @PardeepJain binded content is not visible in the editor. but if i type something in the editor it replaces the binded variable content. It means binding is working, but only content is not visible.